# Find the potential of $v_1$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

so I wanted to compare my computations in order to know whether they're flawless:

Given the vector field $v_2(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 2x_1x_2x_3\\x_1^2x_3\\x_1^2x_2 \end{pmatrix}$ and using line integration, integrating along $K: \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}\overset{K_1}\longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} x\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}\overset{K_2}\longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\0 \end{pmatrix}\overset{K_3}\longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z \end{pmatrix}$, I found: $$f(x,y,z)=\int_{0}^{x}f_x(t,0,0) \, dt+\int_{0}^{y}f_y(x,t,0) \, dt+\int_{0}^{z}f_z(x,y,t) \, dt=\int_{0}^{x}0 \, dt+\int_{0}^{y} \, 0 \, dt+\int_{0}^{z}x^2y \, dt=x^2yz+C $$

by solving $$\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 2x_1x_2x_3\\x_1^2x_3\\x_1^2x_2 \end{pmatrix}\overset{!}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} f_x\\f_y\\f_z \end{pmatrix}=\nabla f$$

When deriving $f(x,y,z)$ it's correct, but is the computation fine?

Comment: Well, strictly speaking $v_2$ is a function of $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$, so you shouldn’t be using $x$, $y$ and $z$. Did you check that the vector field is irrotational so that your computation is a valid way to find a primitive in the first place? Most importantly, you’ve lost a factor of $1/2$ somewhere along the way.

Comment: Note that you could also integrate directly along the line segment from the origin to $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ using the parameterization $(tx_1,tx_2,tx_3)$, $t\in[0,1]$. The integrand simplifies to an expression in $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ times a power of $t$.